# Is there any disadvanteage to using DataLayers instead of SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am making a wear app that should work as standalone, but also be able to sync up with a phone if someone has one. And also work on just a phone too.

Now for the synced version I will use DataLayers do save the Data, because both devices have to access it. But what about when there is a single app? Can I just continue using DataLayers the same way I would with SharedPreferences? Is there any disadvantage not to recode the apps to use SharedPref instead of Datalayers if they work alone?

Answer (score 0):

Using the wearable `DataAPI` to store data if it's actually meant to get synced over is generally fine, but there are a few downsides:

- Writing a data item will consume network traffic so will consume more battery than writing to memory/disk, which is an issue if you're writing changes from the phone/watch frequently.
- You can't read data synchronously and there's no guarantees on when the PendingResult will return (or if it will even return w/o an error), whereas with `SharedPreferences` you don't have this issue.